# Significant differences between PHPs memory_get_peak_usage() on Windows vs. OS X

Tags: windows, php, mac-osx, memory-usage

Can anyone explain why the same PHP application running on a Windows server reports memory_get_peak_usage() as ~3.25mb, but on OS X gives ~19.5mb?

Obviously one is *very* wrong, but I don't know which to believe.

Comment: First obvious thing to ask is are you running the same version of PHP on both, with exactly the same modules loaded?

Comment: Yup both running the same version of PHP. All the same extensions as far as I'm aware, although I've not checked every extension version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What SAPI (server API) is php run under?  With some SAPI's, the memory_usage functions return the memory of the entire process (including the PHP interpreter and web server client) whereas others return just the scripts memory usage (Minus the overhead).  So likely neither is wrong, they are just describing different things...

Comment: Well they're both running as modules under Apache, so I thought they should be the same? Maybe not though?

Comment: @Jack Sleight: Both under mod_php?  What worker style (prefork?  threaded?)?  I think tracking down the differences would be your best bet for figuring out what's going on...

Comment: Both under mod_php yes, but "What worker style (prefork? threaded?)?" is a bit beyond my knowledge... I'll try to find out.